# BusinessObjects - DIsplaying Integers Instead of Decimals in a Chart

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I have a column chart with 2 measures on y-axis.
The values display numbers in decimal format.

My question is - how can I configure the chart, so it displays the numbers in integer format?
(I am using WebIntelligence, BusinessObjects 4.0)

Edit 1: The chart in question is mixed chart (column and line chart).
There are 3 measures - 2 are displayed as columns, one as line.
Every measure has on top the corresponding value.

Edit 2: I managed to transform decimals into integers. However, now one of my columns turned into line, and I can't find how to undo that. So the question is - where can I edit (in mixed chart) which measures should be represented as columns and which as lines?

Comment: Your "Edit 2" is a different question, you should ask a **new one**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the chart's formatting options (right-click > Format Chart), go to the Global settings and then Measure Properties.  It should be third from the top (General, Area Display, Measure Properties...).  From there you can change the display type of the measures in your chart (Bars, Lines, Surfaces).